# Spring Boot Reactive WebClient "serverWebExchange must be null" when Spring Security OAuth is in use

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I would like to use a WebClient from a Spring Boot WebFlux app that is set up with Spring Security OAuth 2 Client Credentials.

But, I get: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: serverWebExchange must be null`

The code is here: https://github.com/mparaz/spring-apigee-client

When I disable Spring Security by removing it from the `pom.xml`, it works properly.

When I keep using Spring Security, but instead of returning the `webClient()` chain result to the controller, and just prints it out, it also works.

It looks like the Reactive client and server don't work together when Spring Security is used. How could I get them running together?

Comment: You have setup the webclient with the unauthenticated repo/exchange. Essentially it expects null or anonymous authentication on the Reactive servlet context holder.  when it makes the call

Comment: Thanks @DarrenForsythe . Could you suggest what I should be doing instead, in https://github.com/mparaz/spring-apigee-client/blob/develop/src/main/java/com/example/springapigeeclient/SpringApigeeClientApplication.java ? Instead of: 

ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations,
new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());

Comment: Should be able to autowire `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` in, there's only two concrete impls available. UnAuthenticated being the other for requests that do not have a principal assoicated with it

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. When I invoke an oauth2 client credentials protected resource through a unit test, everything is fine. But when I invoke it through a unauthenticated rest request, it seems to propagate the reactive servlet context holder, instead of making a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that if you use an `UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` it will propagate the webExchange from the source request going into to your `@RestController` into the `WebClient` you are using to invoke the other service causing the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: serverWebExchange must be null`

To fix this, use the autowired implementation of the `ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository` (this happens to be `AuthenticatedPrincipalServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository`)

```
    @Bean
    @LoadBalanced
    public WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder(ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrations,
                                                          ObjectMapper objectMapper,
                                                          ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository clientRepository) {

        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth2ClientFilter = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(
                clientRegistrations,
                clientRepository);
        oauth2ClientFilter.setDefaultClientRegistrationId("apigee");
        WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder();
        builder.defaultHeader("Content-Type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        builder.defaultHeader("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString());
        builder.filter(oauth2ClientFilter);
        return builder;
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

For me the problem was following

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.5.x/reference/html5/#oauth2Client-authorized-manager-provider

```
The DefaultOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager is designed to be used within the context of a HttpServletRequest. When operating outside of a HttpServletRequest context, use AuthorizedClientServiceOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager instead.
```

Comment on the following link worked for me

```
https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/spring-projects/spring-security/8444/621567261
```

Another link

```
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/8230
```

Comment

```
DefaultReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager is intended to be used within a request context.

Given that you're seeing serverWebExchange cannot be null, you must be operating outside of a request context, which in case you should use AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager instead.

NOTE: Change the ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository parameter to ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService.
```

Actual code

```
    @Bean
    fun serverOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(clientRegistrations: List<ClientRegistration>)
            : ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction {
        val clientRegistrationRepository = InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistrations)
        val authorizedClientService = InMemoryReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository)

        val oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager = AuthorizedClientServiceReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager(
            clientRegistrationRepository,
            authorizedClientService
        )
        val filterFunction = ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(oAuth2AuthorizedClientManager)
        filterFunction.setDefaultClientRegistrationId(clientId)
        return filterFunction
    }
```

Comment: The ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction constructor requires a type of ReactiveOAuth2AuthorizedClientManager. Your "Actual Code" won't compile.

Comment: This code causes different behavior. The constructor with the client manager ignores the 401 status code from the server.